# Tracker service not working on some devices

Tags: java, android, service, background-service, android-device-monitor

I have written an application for Tracker; with a service that runs every 5 minutes. It works fine on Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime (Android 7.0) and Samsung Galaxy Tab A (Android 7.1), But when I run on Lenovo A2010 (Android 5.1), the service does not work. I don't know whether it is my code or my device which is causing the problem.

This is the log from when the service stopped:

```
10-08 09:01:31.122 721-737/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateAllPhoneStateLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:3321)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:3351)
    at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.notePhoneSignalStrength(BatteryStatsService.java:395)
    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastSignalStrengthChanged(TelephonyRegistry.java:1448)
    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifySignalStrengthForSubscriber(TelephonyRegistry.java:869)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact(ITelephonyRegistry.java:184)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
```

And here is my service, `AppService.java`:

```
public class AppService extends Service {
    private MyThread thread;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    private static final String tracker = "Tracker";
    String result=null,status=null,statusresult=null;
    String stusername;
    String imeiids;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!thread.isAlive()) {      
            thread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (thread.isAlive()) {      
            stopService(new Intent(this, AppService.class));
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(AppService.this,"Start...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        thread = new MyThread();
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(tracker, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        stusername = shared.getString("username", "not found!").toString();
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            TelephonyManager c=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
            if(c.getDeviceId()==null){
                editor.commit();
            }
            else{
                editor.putString("imeiid", c.getDeviceId());
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread { 
        private static final String tag = "Sevice Demo";
        private static final int delay = 60000;//60000=30sec/1minute
        private int roundNumber = 0;
        private boolean finishService = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
                wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
                wl.acquire();

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppService.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    TelephonyManager c=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    imeiids = c.getDeviceId();
                }
                if(imeiids== null){
                    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(tracker, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    imeiids=shared.getString("imeiid", "").toString();
                }

                Date current = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                final String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(current);

                if(!stusername.equals("not found!")){

                    //////////////////////////////////// Open GPS //////////////////////////////////////
                    int off=0;
                    try {
                        off = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
                    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(off==0){
                        Intent onGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(onGPS);
                    }

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String formattedDateString = formatter.format(currentTime);

                    SimpleDateFormat formatstr = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
                    final String formattedDayString = formatstr.format(currentTime);

                    if (!haveNetworkConnection()) {
                        /*no network connect*/
                    }
                    else{
                        Cursor res = myDb.getDatasync(stusername);
                        if(res.getCount()==0){
                            Log.d("dddd", "no data");
                        }
                        else{
                            String datetimes=null,lats=null,longs=null;
                                res.moveToFirst();
                                do{
                                    final String ids=res.getString(0);
                                    datetimes=res.getString(1);
                                    lats=res.getString(3);
                                    longs=res.getString(4);
                                    final String finalDatetimes = datetimes;
                                    final String finalLats = lats;
                                    final String finalLongs = longs;
                                    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
                                        @Override
                                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                            String location_url = "http://_____._________/__________/______________________.php";
                                            try {
                                                URL url = new URL(location_url);
                                                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                                                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                                                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                                                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                                                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                                                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("staffcode", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(stusername, "UTF-8")+ "&"
                                                        + URLEncoder.encode("dateTime", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(finalDatetimes, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                                        + URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(finalLats, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                                        + URLEncoder.encode("lon", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(finalLongs, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                                        + URLEncoder.encode("imei", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(imeiids, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                                        + URLEncoder.encode("app", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("T:1.0", "UTF-8");
                                                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                                                bufferedWriter.flush();
                                                bufferedWriter.close();
                                                outputStream.close();
                                                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                                                String line = "";
                                                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                                    result = line;
                                                }
                                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++)
                                                {
                                                    status=(jsonObject.getString("status"));                 //Get Status
                                                    statusresult=(jsonObject.getString("statusresult"));           
                                                }
                                                bufferedReader.close();
                                                inputStream.close();
                                                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            return null;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                                            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                                            if(status.equals("success")&& statusresult.equals("success")){
                                                boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateDatasync(ids);
                                                if(isUpdate) {
                                                    Log.d("Get Data ", "Updated");
                                                }
                                                else  {
                                                    Log.d("Get Data ", "not updated");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else{

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }.execute();
                                }while(res.moveToNext());

                        }
                    }

                    Cursor res = myDb.getData(stusername);
                    if (res.getCount() ==0) { 
        Log.d("dddd", "no data");
                    }
                    else {
                        res.moveToFirst();
                        do{
                            String asubstring = String.valueOf(res.getString(1)).substring(11, 16);
                            String datesub = res.getString(1).substring(0, 10);
                            if(currentDateandTime.equals(datesub)){    /* Today */ }
                            else{                                       
        //Not Today
                                if(!res.getString(5).equals("1")) { }
                                else{                                   // If Sync = 1      = Sync Success
                                    boolean isDeleteSync = myDb.deleteDataSync(res.getString(0));
                                    if(isDeleteSync) {
                                        Log.d("Log Delete ", "Deleted");
                                    }
                                    else  {
                                        Log.d("Log Delete ", "Can't Deleted");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }while(res.moveToNext());
                    }


                    if (formattedDayString.equals("Sun")) {
                    }
                    else {
                        String hour = formattedDateString.substring(11, 13);
                        String minute = formattedDateString.substring(14, 16);
                        Integer ins = Integer.parseInt(minute);

                        if (hour.equals("08") || hour.equals("09") || hour.equals("10") || hour.equals("11") || hour.equals("12")
                                || hour.equals("13") || hour.equals("14") || hour.equals("15") || hour.equals("16") || hour.equals("17")
                                || hour.equals("18")) {
                            if((hour.equals("18"))&&(ins<=0)){             
                                SimpleDateFormat formatterss = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                                String DateString = formatterss.format(currentTime);
                                String subtime= DateString.substring(3,5);
                                Integer minuteif=Integer.parseInt(subtime);
                                if(minuteif%5==0){
                                    startService(new Intent(AppService.this, GetLocation.class));
                                }
                            }
                            if((!hour.equals("18"))){    
                                SimpleDateFormat formatterss = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                                String DateString = formatterss.format(currentTime);
                                String subtime= DateString.substring(3,5);
                                Integer minuteif=Integer.parseInt(subtime);
                                if(minuteif%5==0){
                                    startService(new Intent(AppService.this, GetLocation.class));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        stopService(new Intent(AppService.this,GetLocation.class));
                        sleep(delay);
                        run();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    wl.release();
                    if (finishService) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
}
```

It's my **DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Tracker.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "LocationMessenger";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";           
public static final String COL_2 = "DATE";     
public static final String COL_3 = "USERNAME";    
public static final String COL_4 = "LATITUDE";      
public static final String COL_5 = "LONGITUDE";      
public static final String COL_6 = "SYNC";        

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "DATE TEXT,USERNAME TEXT,LATITUDE TEXT,LONGITUDE TEXT,SYNC TEXT )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String dates,String username,String latitude,String longitude) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,dates);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,latitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,longitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,"0");
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean insertDataSuccess(String dates,String username,String latitude,String longitude) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,dates);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,latitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,longitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,"1");
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getData(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where USERNAME= ? ",new String[] { username });
    return res;
}

public Cursor getDataforsync(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_3,id);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,"0");
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where ID= ? and SYNC = ?",new String[] { id,"0" });
    return res;
}

public Cursor getDatasync(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,"0");
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where USERNAME= ? and SYNC = ?",new String[] { username,"0" });
    return res;
}

public boolean deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    long rows = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    db.close();
    if(rows == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}

public boolean deleteDataSync(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    long rows = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] { id });
    db.close();
    if(rows == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean updateDatasync(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_6,"1");
    long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"ID=" + id,null);
    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is array exception you are using array index more than its length.

Comment: Attached Debugger on this line,
 Cursor res = myDb.getDatasync(stusername);
                        if(res.getCount()==0)
Check how many indexes are in res variable.
It might be crashing here.

Comment: There are four places where you might getting this exception.
you can check where you are getting it by debugging or by put logs on these lines.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you tell me where I use array index?? I'm beginner pls... :)

Comment: final String ids=res.getString(0);
                                    datetimes=res.getString(1);
                                    lats=res.getString(3);
                                    longs=res.getString(4);

Put debugger here and watch how many indexes are in "res" variable ?

Comment: getDatasync(stusername), Share this method code ?

Comment: public Cursor getDatasync(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,"0");
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where USERNAME= ? and SYNC = ?",new String[] { username,"0" });
        return res;
    }

Comment: Share Table structure where you are fetching this record ?

Comment: I share below thankful :) - Syed Hamza Hassan

Comment: Ok got it, you are accessing extra index here,
 if(!res.getString(5).equals("1")), you need to use if(!res.getString(4).equals("1")) here
because you have 5 indexes in array.

Comment: I think, I have 6 indexs is ID, DATE, USERNAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, SYNC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181455/discussion-between-syed-hamza-hassan-and-sirinan-jirinsa).